# How to check if a value is equal or not equal to one of multiple values in Lua?

Tags: if-statement, variables, lua, comparison, operators

I am trying to verify that a variable is not equal to either `0` or `1`. I tried using the following but neither work:

```
if x ~= (0 or 1) then
    print("x is not equal to 1 or 0")
end
```

```
if x ~= 0 or 1 then
    print("x is not equal to 1 or 0")
end
```

Conversely using `==` in this manner does not work either:

```
if x == (0 or 1) then
    print("x is equal to 1 or 0")
end
```

```
if x == 0 or 1 then
    print("x is equal to 1 or 0")
    return
end
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40035859/16217248)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Your problem stems from a misunderstanding of the `or` operator that is common to people learning programming languages like this. Yes, your immediate problem can be solved by writing [`x ~= 0 and x ~= 1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11659129), but I'll go into a little more detail about why your attempted solution doesn't work.

When you read `x ~= (0 or 1)` or `x ~= 0 or 1` it's natural to parse this as you would the sentence "x is not equal to zero or one".  In the ordinary understanding of that statement, "x" is the subject, "is not equal to" is the predicate or verb phrase, and "zero or one" is the object, a set of possibilities joined by a conjunction.  You apply the subject with the verb to each item in the set.

However, Lua does not parse this based on the rules of English grammar, it parses it in binary comparisons of two elements based on its order of operations. Each operator has a [precedence](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.7) which determines the order in which it will be evaluated.  `or` has a lower precedence than `~=`, just as addition in mathematics has a lower precedence than multiplication.  Everything has a lower precedence than parentheses.

As a result, when evaluating `x ~= (0 or 1)`, the interpreter will first compute `0 or 1` (because of the parentheses) and then `x ~=` the result of the first computation, and in the second example, it will compute `x ~= 0` and then apply the result of that computation to `or 1`.

The [logical operator `or`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.4) "returns its first argument if this value is different from nil and false; otherwise, or returns its second argument".  The [relational operator `~=`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.3) is the inverse of the equality operator `==`; it returns true if its arguments are different types (x *is* a number, right?), and otherwise compares its arguments normally.

Using these rules, `x ~= (0 or 1)` will decompose to `x ~= 0` (after applying the `or` operator) and this will return 'true' if x is anything other than 0, including 1, which is undesirable.  The other form,  `x ~= 0 or 1` will first evaluate `x ~= 0` (which may return true or false, depending on the value of x).  Then, it will decompose to one of `false or 1` or  `true or 1`.  In the first case, the statement will return `1`, and in the second case, the statement will return `true`.  Because control structures in Lua only consider `nil` and `false` to be false, and anything else to be true, this will always enter the `if` statement, which is not what you want either.

There is no way that you can use binary operators like those provided in programming languages to compare a single variable to a list of values.  Instead, you need to compare the variable to each value one by one.  There are a few ways to do this.  The simplest way is to use [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to express the statement 'not one or zero' (which can't be evaluated with binary operators) as 'not one and not zero', which can trivially be written with binary operators:

```
if x ~= 1 and x ~= 0 then
    print( "X must be equal to 1 or 0" )
    return
end
```

Alternatively, you can use a loop to check these values:

```
local x_is_ok = false
for i = 0,1 do 
    if x == i then
        x_is_ok = true
    end
end
if not x_is_ok then
    print( "X must be equal to 1 or 0" )
    return
end
```

Finally, you could use relational operators to check a range and then test that x was an integer in the range (you don't want 0.5, right?)

```
if not (x >= 0 and x <= 1 and math.floor(x) == x) then
    print( "X must be equal to 1 or 0" )
    return
end
```

Note that I wrote `x >= 0 and x <= 1`.  If you understood the above explanation, you should now be able to explain why I didn't write `0 <= x <= 1`, and what this erroneous expression would return!

Comment: Thanks, that explains it perfectly!

Comment: You should teach programming classes if you don't already. :)

Comment: I do not know much about Lua, but maybe you should mention that one can also use `if not (x == 1 or x == 0) then`, in connection with your mention of De Morgan's law.

Answer (score 11):

For testing only two values, I'd personally do this:

```
if x ~= 0 and x ~= 1 then
    print( "X must be equal to 1 or 0" )
    return
end
```

If you need to test against more than two values, I'd stuff your choices in a table acting like a set, like so:

```
choices = {[0]=true, [1]=true, [3]=true, [5]=true, [7]=true, [11]=true}

if not choices[x] then
    print("x must be in the first six prime numbers")
    return
end
```

Answer (score 5):

`x ~= 0 or 1` is the same as `((x ~= 0) or 1)`

`x ~=(0 or 1)` is the same as `(x ~= 0)`.

try something like this instead.

```
function isNot0Or1(x)
    return (x ~= 0 and x ~= 1)
end

print( isNot0Or1(-1) == true )
print( isNot0Or1(0) == false )
print( isNot0Or1(1) == false )
```