# Determine if variable is one of several values in Lua

Tags: lua, readability

I have a value `armyName` and need a function that checks if it is one of 8 values. As I'm quite new to Lua, I'm looking for what the best way to do this kind of check is.

This works:

```
local function isPlayerArmyName(armyName)
    return armyName == "ARMY_1"
        or armyName == "ARMY_2"
        or armyName == "ARMY_3"
        or armyName == "ARMY_4"
        or armyName == "ARMY_5"
        or armyName == "ARMY_6"
        or armyName == "ARMY_7"
        or armyName == "ARMY_8"
end
```

This also works:

```
local function isPlayerArmyName(armyName)
    local names = {
        ["ARMY_1"] = true,  ["ARMY_2"] = true, ["ARMY_3"] = true, ["ARMY_4"] = true,
        ["ARMY_5"] = true,  ["ARMY_6"] = true, ["ARMY_7"] = true, ["ARMY_8"] = true,
    }

    return names[armyName] or false
end
```

They are both rather silly compared to this PHP code:

```
return in_array( $armyName, [ "ARMY_1", "ARMY_2", "ARMY_3", ..., "ARMY_8" ] )
```

Is there a better way to make such a check than the provided Lua code snippets? And if not, what would the typical Lua programmer prefer to come across; the first or second one?

I'm using Lua 5.0.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11658975/16217248)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this as well:

```
local names = {"ARMY_1", "ARMY_2", "ARMY_3", "ARMY_4", "ARMY_5", "ARMY_6", "ARMY_7", "ARMY_8"}

local function isPlayerArmyName(armyName)
    for index = 1, #names do
        if names[index] == armyName then
            return true
        end
    end
end
```

This option is scalable, since you can add new armies in case your implementation needs to change. You could extract the `for` part to your own `in_array` function, which you can use in all your code:

```
local function in_array(value, array)
    for index = 1, #array do
        if array[index] == value then
            return true
        end
    end

    return false -- We could ommit this part, as nil is like false
end

local armyNames = {"ARMY_1", "ARMY_2", "ARMY_3", "ARMY_4", "ARMY_5", "ARMY_6", "ARMY_7", "ARMY_8"}

local function isPlayerArmyName(armyName)
    return in_array(armyName, armyNames)
end
```

This implementation might be a bit slower than your second option, since your second option uses keys. Your second option is not bad, it might even be the fastest. It does look silly, but it is easily configurable.

You could also use a pattern match, if the table is not necessary and will stick to that army naming convention:

```
local function isPlayerArmyName(armyName)
    return (string.match(armyName, "^ARMY_[1-8]$")) ~= nil
end
```

You can even remove the `~= nil`, since it will return a string, which is also true in Lua:

```
local function isPlayerArmyName(armyName)
    return string.match(armyName, "^ARMY_[1-8]$")
end

if isPlayerArmyName("ARMY_1") then
    -- This will be executed, since it returned "ARMY_1", which evaluates to true
end

if isPlayerArmyName("ARMY_9") then
    -- This will not be executed, since the function returned nil.
end
```

As for the first example you provide, i would not recommend doing that as it is not modular or scalable, not in Lua and not in any other language.

Comment: I don't like your solution because you make a new table everytime you call the function.

Comment: Really? This is just an example code. I don't see why creating a table (which will be GC eventually) is such a concern. Anyway, Your solution also creates a table, if i were to call it that way all the time.

Comment: Our coded are very different though. I allow customizing the table each call, there's no reason why you can't store yours in an upvalue. (I'm big on efficiency, and very nit picky, so ignore me if you want.)

Comment: "I don't like your solution because you make a new table everytime you call the function." I don't see why you like yours then, considering it does the exact same thing: create a table every time you call the function. Anyway, i updated the code so that you can "like it". Not that it matters though, if you are so big on efficiency then i don't see why you are using lua, instead of C++ or anything faster, where memory leaks really matter.

Comment: "Our codes are very different though. I allow customizing the table each call". Mine can easily be used multiple times with a table Pre-made. Yours forced a new table creation with no reason for it.

Answer (score 3):

```
function in_dictionary(val,dict)
    return dict[val]
end

print(in_dictionary("potatoes", {apples = true, potatoes = true, oranges = true}))
```

Probably the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
function in_array(v, t)
  for i=1,#t do
    if v == t[i] then return true end
  end
end

if in_array(v, {....}) then .... end
```

Comment: @Vyacheslav I think the idea here is that this is how you would implement the equivalent to PHP's `in_array`, and that there are different tools for different data structures. I will say that code-only answers are not a great thing.